# Cessna 182 Climb Performance

Tags: cessna-182

I have this in the POH for a 182P I'm renting. I am failing to understand the lower table on the performance page. It says that for a gross weight of 2,950 at sea level and 59F, I can expect a climb rate of 890 ft/min. That's fine. But then, it says 1.5g of fuel used - for what? Per minute? Or? And then at 5,000 ft I can expect 3.8g of fuel burn from sea level - again - from sea level to what altitude? 5,000 ft?

I'm sorry if this is obvious to everyone but me

Thanks in advance!

[image: Performance table for 182P]

Answer (score 2):

The 1.5 gallons of fuel is used up for "warm-up and takeoff," (see note #2). The 3.8 gallons of fuel are used from Sea Level to 5000 feet MSL.

Note that the 1.5 gallons remains the same for all gross weights because you are warming up and making the takeoff and the different weights of the aircraft are not a factor.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case where we have to read the notes associated with the performance chart very carefully and understand what is going on.  Note 2 states: “Fuel used includes warm up and take off allowance” ie from the time you start up your engine on the ramp to the time you are climbing away from the airport, you will burn approx 1.5 gal of fuel. To reach 5000 ft @ stp and MTOW, you will burn another 2.3 gal during the climb giving a total fuel usage at this point of 3.8 gal.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and help!